# How can I have an application menu like macOS?

Tags: 18.04, menu, menu-bar, globalmenu

This is how application menu on my Mac.

[image]

[image]

And this is on ubuntu 18.04.
There is only a menu item `quit` inside Pycharm on the top bar, other menu items like File, Edit, View are on the different bar, how can I make it look like macOS?

[image]

BTW, when I googling it, I found [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/). but looks like it doesn't work on 18.04 and makes system unstable.

Comment: Not possible as of now with GNOME (except possibly using the buggy extension you have mentioned), you may try Unity.

Comment: @pomsky ahh, this is totally unacceptable, any flavors can do make it?

Comment: Most probably Ubuntu MATE has the feature.

Comment: I wonder why Ubuntu can stand this kind of menu display...

Comment: KDE also has a global application menu widget.

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact that Unity has it. It's slightly hidden though. It only shows when you are hovering your mouse over title bar.

Answer (score 1):

GNOME cannot do this.

Unity can and is still available in the 20.04 repositories. Or, you can try the free Ubuntu Unity remix -- https://ubuntuunity.org/

I am running this on 1 machine and it's pretty good. Not perfect but it works.

Alternatively, I believe that both MATE and KDE 5 can be customised to look and work in a Mac-like manner, with a global menu bar at the top of the screen and a dock for launching and switching apps along one screen edge. I have not tried this myself, though.

KDE: https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/plasma-look-like-mac.html

MATE: http://mate-macos.blogspot.com/p/making-ubuntu-mate-look-like-macos.html

Of course both MATE and KDE have Ubuntu flavours.